# Problem with batch mode Saga Raster Calculator

Tags: qgis, raster, qgis-plugins, saga

I have to do a couple of raster multiplications for which the batch mode would save me a lot of time. But the only thing I get are rasters that contain nothing but *nan* values. If I multiply the rasters one by one without batch mode, it works well. the batch mode also works with the same rasters doing other operations like additions or the gt() command. The *Grids product* tool shows the same behavior.

Sometimes I also get the alert *Oooops! The following output layers could not be open* which disappears after restarting QGIS.

To me it seems like that is a bug, is there another easy way to do those operations automatically? Let me know if you need the text from the Log File.

Edit: I know there is another Raster Calculator in GRASS, but to use this one i'd have to import all layers to GRASS which would take me a lot of time as well I fear.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I tried around a little more and it only works fine if I select the layers from the file system instead of the open layers table.